# PHP Update Subtract Current Value by 1

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi was wondering if there is a quick way of updating a record in my table but subtracting whatever the current value is by 1 if it's not 0.

I know I can do this by first doing a

```
SELECT countField FROM myTable Where id="1";
```

Then get the countField Value and subtract 1 from that value.

Finally:

```
Update myTable ... etc
```

Is there a way of doing this without having to do a SELECT and after an UPDATE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET countField = countField - 1 WHERE ...
```